# Exercises for Linear Regression Models

Tags: regression, references, linear-model

I am looking for exercises (more theoretical than applied) about linear regression models. Maybe you can advice me where I can find such exercises. Here is what my linear models course deals with if you want an idea :

- Properties of the multivariate Gaussian distribution and related quadratic forms.
- Gaussian linear regression: likelihood, least squares, geometrical interpretation.
- Distribution theory, confidence and prediction intervals.
- Gauss-Markov theorem.
- Model checking and validation: residual diagnostics, outliers and leverage points.
- Analysis of variance.
- Model selection: bias/variance tradeoff, stepwise procedures, information-based criteria.
- Multicollinearity and penalised estimation: ridge regression, LASSO.
- Robust regression and M-estimation.
- Nonparametric regression and smoothing splines.

Comment: Cross Validated!

Comment: @Dave nice one haha didn't see it coming. I do that when I completely mastered a course but I am not fully at ease with linear models yet.

Comment: Aren't you following any textbook like Searle; Seber, Lee; Montgomery et al; Christensen etc? These books do have some decent problems to test your theoretical skills.

Comment: @User1865345 No, my teacher uses his own course but I'll have a look at all the books you listed, thanks !

Comment: @Kilkik that's good. Pick any and you would encounter some easy to moderate problems to test your concepts. On a second note, you can ask your lecturer to provide any competent set of problems based on their notes that you might practice.